# FaceID unlock with Apple Watch while wearing a mask support in app

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, face-id, localauthentication

As you may know, Apple introduced a feature in iOS 14.5, that allow users to unlock their iPhones using FaceID, while wearing a mask, if they are wearing their Apple Watch.

It works flawlessly in iOS, nevertheless 3rd party apps which are using FaceID (LocalAuthentication) are not recognizing face with mask in the same way.

Did Apple not make it available to apps, or do we need extra configuration to make this feature available in our apps?

I cannot find any documentation about the matter.
I checked: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication

Comment: Which 3rd parties you are working with ?

Comment: Some banking apps that I'm using and/or our own product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible as apple hasn't enabled it for apps.
Imagine a banking application that authenticates using Face Id with a mask.
Another example is that you cannot unlock your saved passwords in settings while wearing a mask.